# how can I print all together at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I've this code below, the idea is when a user provide arguments( singer/s name ) , it saves it and go to the URL of each (singer ) and print all the songs and go to the next (singer name ) url and print all the songs, and So On,

the issue in this code is, when it prints for the first (singer) and goes to the next , it prints the ( First and the Second Together AGAIN )

like ( First,  ( first + Second ) , ( first, Second, Third ) ... )

how do I print the whole thing once, like all together ONE TIME.. ??

I tried to print in some places in the code, it won't work,
and when I tried to print `console.log(mailoutput);` it works inside the `each loop` but outside it, it shows it's `Undefined`

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var urls = [];
var mailoutput ;
var songs = [];



// save all arguments into an array
for (let j = 2; j < process.argv.length; j++) {
    urls.push(process.argv[j]);
}

// loop through the array
for(var i =0; i<urls.length; i++){

 request('https://www.billboard.com/music/'+urls[i], function(error,response,body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){

var $ = cheerio.load(body);

var title = $('a.artist,div.artist-name').each(function(i, element) {
  mailoutput = $(this).text();
 //console.log(mailoutput);
  songs= songs +mailoutput;

});

}  // END OF IF ERROR
  console.log(songs);

});   // end of the REQUEST here

}  // end of the LOOP here ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```

```
for(var i =0; i<urls.length; i++){
    request('https://www.billboard.com/music/'+urls[i], function(error,response,body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var title = $('a.artist,div.artist-name').text();
            console.log(title);
        }
    });
}
```

```

Comment: a small issue now when i try to print the title outside the request, it shows it undefined some reason, but than u anyway

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the code a bit

Instead of:-

```
songs= songs +mailoutput;
```

do:-

```
songs.push(mailoutput);
```

***Full code need to be:-***

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var urls = [];
var mailoutput ;
var songs = [];

for (let j = 2; j < process.argv.length; j++) {
    urls.push(process.argv[j]);
}
for(var i =0; i<urls.length; i++){
    request('https://www.billboard.com/music/'+urls[i], function(error,response,body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var title = $('a.artist,div.artist-name').each(function(i, element) {
                mailoutput = $(this).text();
                songs.push(mailoutput); // you define as array so push values to array
            });
        }
    });
}
console.log(songs);
```

Comment: thank you sir, I did the array, and I push elements ur way, still same, I think it's somthing about the callback function"Request" but not sure how to fix it